# Can we scale Application on Google cloud compute without Google autoscaler?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

I am trying to setup application on Google cloud compute. But I want to setup scaling script that would launch VM instances on google cloud based on some criteria. So Google provides autoscaler options for this, But is it possible to do that without autoscaler through Google APIs??

Also I would like to know procedure for creating image on google cloud compute. I have created one Instance group with instance template that launched one VM instance. But when I try to create image from new image option but it doesn't list disk of that instance.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you can write your own auto scaler. Every google compute engine machine can be accessed through a remote api: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/

You can host your own auto scaler on App Engine with a cron checking the machine health and CPU every 1 minute for example.

Please write a new SO question for the second question.